# Pywin32 update word document via scheduler

Tags: python, sql-server, pywin32

I have some simple code which opens a word document, updates the fields in it, then closes it. This code works correctly when I manually run it, however when I run it via the SQL Server Agent, I get an error. The user that SQL Server Agent runs with is the same user I am logged in with when running manually. I know the agent can 'see' the document because earlier code used in the task actually creates this document.

Code:

```
import win32com.client
word = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
filePath = "\\\\network\\data\\file.docx"
doc = word.Documents.Open(filePath)
doc.TablesOfContents(1).Update()
doc.Close(SaveChanges=True)
word.Quit()
```

Error:

> Executed as user: DOMAIN\User. Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "\\network\data\file.docx", line 8, in 
> doc.TablesOfContents(1).Update()  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object
> has no attribute 'TablesOfContents'

Why might this behavior happen?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future that might get this issue, I fixed it like this:

1. Open dcomcnfg Navigate to Component Services>Computers>My
   Computer>DCOM Config>Microsoft Word 97-2003 Document
2. Right-click, click Properties
3. Select the Identity Tab
4. Select 'The Interactive User'